# Getting Error With geolocator: ^3.0.0 in flutter if i add in pubspec.yaml file, not able to build android app

Tags: android, flutter

If I add `geolocator: ^3.0.0` in `pubspec.yaml` file in Flutter my Android app not able to build and throwing an error like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

I have tried changing the target and buildtool version from 27 to 28 still getting same issue

build.gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.depl.toours.business"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

main.dart file.

```
  class MyDemoPage extends State<AccommodationPage> {
        @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();
                propertyList = new List<String>();
                propertyList.add('Hotel');
                propertyList.add('Gust House');
                _getCurrentPosition();
              }

              _getCurrentPosition() async{
                GeolocationStatus status = await Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(locationPermission: GeolocationPermission.location);
                print('GPS: $status');
               Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
               double lat = position.latitude;
               double lng = position.longitude;
               print('LatLng: ${lat} & ${lng}');
              }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Accommodation'),
      ),
      body: _getBody(),
    );
  }

    }
```

Am expecting current location co-ordinates from the `geolocator: ^3.0.0` package and also included `multidexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig` (`build.gradle` file).

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need to use

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

In your setup this is missing

```
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
```

or if you need to support min SDK < 21

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

In your setup this is missing

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

For more details see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex